# Removing hidden vertices of 3d models in opengles

Tags: algorithm, graphics, opengl-es

I have a 3d humanoid model on which i can position an model of a shirt. In this state opengl rendering is having the typical z-fighting problem. I found that the only solution is to prevent the hidden vertices from rendering. Is there some way to automatically prevent hidden vertices from rendering or any algorithm to remove the hidden vertices

Comment: If it is really Z-fighting and not intersecting meshes then  you can try `glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);` or not use depth test at all and use Z-sorting instead by multi pass render with `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);` and different settings of `glFrontFace(GL_CCW);` and `glFrontFace(GL_CW);` for each pass so first you render the back side and then the front side ...

Answer (score 2):

A relatively easy way would be to use the stencil buffer. The idea is simple. First draw the the shirt with `glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE)` and `glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 1)`. This sets a bit in the stencil buffer wherever you draw the shirt. Then draw the model with `glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP)` and `glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, 1)`. This will draw your model only when it doesn't touch pixels already drawn by the shirt.

A note on drawbacks: You probably need to segment the model and apply this only to the section you expect to have problems with (say torso), otherwise the technique will occlude other parts of the model that would draw over the shirt (say the arms). For best result make sure you cull the backfaces of the shirt.

Answer (score 2):

If it's genuine z-fighting, i.e. different faces at **the same** depth with which therefore appears in front being more or less random per pixel due to precision variations, also consider a `glPolygonOffset` solution — enable `GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL` and call `glPolygonOffset(1.0, 1.0)` (or use other arguments if you prefer; `1.0` is rote) prior to drawing the shirt. Draw the body either with offset fill disabled or following a `glPolygonOffset(0.0, 0.0)`, which has the same effect.

The polygon offset acts to nudge the depth value of some geometry just a touch before it is subject to the depth test. So this more or less says that the thing you've given the offset too should be in front as long as it is the same or only very slightly behind the thing without the offset.